# How can I stop using the radio in my app?

Tags: cordova, mobile, meteor, ionic-framework

How can I stop my app from using the mobile radio or WiFi while the phone is locked or the app is in the background?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Meteor.disconnect()`.

See the docs here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_disconnect

You'd want to call this after a certain amount of time of inactivity, or on a window changed event.

Make sure to call `Meteor.reconnect()` once the user comes back to using the app.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll give that a try. I think I can use this with the pause and resume Cordova events.